# Upgrading website from IE6 to IE10: Passing combobox as parameter to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-10

I am upgrading my website from IE6 to IE10.

I have a function that moves user choices from one combobox to another

```
//moves options from one selection box (combo box) to another
function MoveElements(FromCombo,ToCombo)
{
    ... code ...
}
```

I defined the two comboboxes as

```
<SELECT NAME="choice1_select" CLASS="Form150" size="7" MULTIPLE>
...
</SELECT>

<SELECT NAME="choice2_select" CLASS="Form150" size="7" MULTIPLE>
...
</SELECT>
```

The code to activate the move from one combobox to another is:

```
MoveElements(choice1_select,choice2_select);
```

This code works well on IE6 but not on IE10. It returns an error

```
SCRIPT5009: 'choice1_select' is undefined
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE10 is relating to `choice1_select` as a variable

Replace the code to activate the move with

```
MoveElements(document.getElementById("choice1_select"),
    document.getElementById("choice2_select"))
```

Change `NAME` to `ID` in the combobox definition

```
<SELECT ID="choice1_select" CLASS="Form150" size="7" MULTIPLE>
...
</SELECT>

<SELECT ID="choice2_select" CLASS="Form150" size="7" MULTIPLE>
...
</SELECT>
```

See also [How do I pass an HTML element as an argument to a Javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518511/how-do-i-pass-an-html-element-as-an-argument-to-a-javascript-function)